# Would bad practice using Wordpress wpdb class lead to SQL injection threats?

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-injection

A previous developer had a bad practice in using the wordpress `wpdb` class by using its 'read from database' methods to actually write to the database...ex:

```
$wpdb->get_results( "UPDATE `table` SET `column1`='$value1', `column2`='$value2' WHERE `coulmn3`= '$condition';",ARRAY_A );
```

The same is done with `INSERT`; always uses `get_results` or `get_row` to insert to the database. Apparently, he/she did not know of the `insert` and `update` methods available.

While the code works fine, **I was wondering if the input would still be escaped by the wpdb class or not and if that would expose the website to SQL injections threats**.

**If yes, then what would be a quick solution to fix this security hole?** 
There would be at least 100 insert/update commands across the website files and would be a hassle to go through each one of them and change to the proper method. If there are no other easier/cleverer ideas, I will go ahead and edit each manually.

Answer (score 1):

The queries, if they are as the one of your example, are exposed to SQL injections.

Wordpress suggests to prevent SQL injection using the function `prepare` of the WPDB class.

```
 <?php $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'query' , value_parameter[, value_parameter ... ] ); ?>
```

I am afraid there is not a quick fix for that rather than recode the query methods calls manually.

Comment: Would  `prepare`ing each individual variable on its own be a possible solution? i.e. `$value1= $wpdb->prepare('%s',$value1);`? and do the same with any variables used in `$condition`. Then I can keep the query method calls as they are.
The point is that there are quite a few queries that are using the same variables....modifying each one will take a lot of time.